# SPARQL query with multiple aggregates exceeds memory limit

Tags: optimization, sparql

I am trying to generate some user statistics from a triple store using SPARQL. Please see the query below. How can this be improved? Am I doing something evil here? Why is this consuming so much memory? (see the background story at the end of this post)

I prefer to do the aggregation and the joins all inside the triple store. Splitting up the query would mean that I had to join the results "manually", outside the database, loosing the efficiency and optimizations of the triple store. No need to reinvent the wheel for no good reason.

**The query**

```
SELECT
    ?person
    (COUNT(DISTINCT ?sent_email) AS ?sent_emails)
    (COUNT(DISTINCT ?received_email) AS ?received_emails)
    (COUNT(DISTINCT ?receivedInCC_email) AS ?receivedInCC_emails)
    (COUNT(DISTINCT ?revision) AS ?commits)

WHERE {
  ?person rdf:type foaf:Person.

  OPTIONAL {
    ?sent_email rdf:type email:Email.
    ?sent_email email:sender ?person.
  }

  OPTIONAL {
    ?received_email rdf:type email:Email.
    ?received_email email:recipient ?person.
  }

  OPTIONAL {
    ?receivedInCC_email rdf:type email:Email.
    ?receivedInCC_email email:ccRecipient ?person.
  }

  OPTIONAL {
    ?revision rdf:type vcs:VcsRevision.
    ?revision vcs:committedBy ?person.
  }
}
GROUP BY ?person
ORDER BY DESC(?commits)
```

**Background**

The problem is that I get the error "QUERY MEMORY LIMIT REACHED" in AllegroGraph (please also see my related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13531088/allegrograph-memorylimit-query-option)). As the repository only contains around 200k triples which easily fit into an (ntriples) input file of ca. 60 MB, I wonder how executing the query results requires more than 4 GB RAM, which is roughly two orders of magnitude higher.

Comment: Given that the code already crashes for reasonably sized input, this doesn't really qualify as "working code". I'm moving this to Stack Overflow where, I think, it's more appropriate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to aggregate over two resources in SPARQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325974/is-it-possible-to-aggregate-over-two-resources-in-sparql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try splitting the computation in sub queries, for example:

```
SELECT
    ?person
    (MAX(?sent_emails_) AS ?sent_emails_)
    (MAX(?received_emails_ AS ?received_emails_)
    (MAX(?receivedInCC_emails_ AS ?receivedInCC_emails_)
    (MAX(?commits_) AS ?commits)
WHERE {
  { 
   SELECT 
          ?person 
          (COUNT(DISTINCT ?sent_email) AS ?sent_emails_) 
          (0 AS ?received_emails_) 
          (0 AS ?commits_) 
   WHERE {
    ?sent_email rdf:type email:Email.
    ?sent_email email:sender ?person.
    ?person rdf:type foaf:Person.
   } GROUP BY ?person 
  } union {
     (similar pattern for the others)
     ....
  }
}
GROUP BY ?person
ORDER BY DESC(?commits)
```

The objective is to:

- avoid the generation of a huge number of rows in the result set that needs to be processed for aggregation
- avoid the use of OPTIONAL{} patterns, that also should affect performance

Comment: There's nothing the matter with that.  According to profile, the asker was here two hours ago, so he'll probably see the answer and get a notification soon.

Comment: Back then, I think I finally ended up with a solution like this.